# Integrating trig functions with $R(\frac {z+1/z} {2}, \frac {z - 1/z} {2i} )$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, reference-request, trigonometry

Someone told me that there is a method for integrating rational functions $R(\cos{\theta}, \sin { \theta})$ by doing contour integration of the complex function $$\frac {R \left( \frac {z + \frac1z} {2}, \frac {z - \frac1z} {2i} \right)} {iz}.$$

I've looked through a couple of Complex Variables textbooks and haven't found it. No results on Uniquation. Does anyone have a reference for this method?

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I didn't know there was a tag for "reference request".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28III.29_.E2.80.93_trigonometric_integrals)

...is a good place to start.

Comment: You are very welcome :)